# How to POST form data to an in-app browser in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, android, html, forms, ionic-framework

I am using the Ionic framework.

I have a form as such:

```
<form action='https://secure.payu.in/_payment' method="POST" target="...">
  ......
</form>
```

Upon form submission, I need the result to open in an in-app browser.

As a dirty hack, I pointed the form submission target as an iframe in the current tab, but I want to avoid this.

Ideally, I need the form action url to open in an in-app browser (and not replace the app in the webview which would result in my loosing control of the app).

I tried to give "_blank" in the target but it doesn't seem to work on the device.

I also know the conventional way to open an in-app browser would be to do something like this:

```
var ref = window.open("http://example.com", "_blank", "location=no");
```

However, what I need is upon the form submission, an in-app browser should open and not triggering an in-app browser via js.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I having the same problem now. If you have done it, can you please share me that code, it will be great help.

Comment: Hi @NitinAgarwal, so what I did was a dirty hack, using an iFrame inside the ionic app. This however isn't safe, though I've seen a lot of mainframe apps using this practice.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem recently. I resolved this by injecting a form with the `executeScript` method.

First, you have to open a transition page (a blank page or other but **with jquery referenced**, you have to host it somewhere) in the appbrowser window:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then, add a `loadstop` listener and call `executeScript` form there (when the URL matches the transition page's URL).

```
 var browserWindow = window.open('http://transitionpage.com', '_blank', 'location=yes,hidden=yes,hardwareback=no');
 var transitionLoaded = false;
 var finalURL = 'https://finalurl.com';
 var paramName = 'SOME_PARAM';
 var paramValue = 'asdf';
 function injectForm() {
    browserWindow.executeScript({
        code: "var $form;$form = $(document.createElement('form')).css({ display: 'none'}).attr('method', 'POST').attr('action', '" + finalURL + "');$('body').append($form);var $input = $(document.createElement('input')).attr('name', '" + paramName + "').val('" + paramValue + "');$form.append($input);$form.submit();"
    }, function() {
        //Form injected
        transitionLoaded = true;
    });
 }
 browserWindow.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
    if (event.url.indexOf('http://transitionpage.com') !== -1 && !transitionLoaded) {
        injectForm();
    }
 });
 browserWindow.show();
```

Comment: Hi @Gustavo Rivas, as i gone through your answer but i have number of parameter, so if you have done with integration, can u please share ur code, that will be great help for me